# Fluent Nhibernate ApplyFilter on Join column

Tags: join, fluent-nhibernate, mapping

I'm trying to apply a filter (ApplyFilter) on a column that is Join (and projected) from another table. I have the following entity:

```
public class User
{
    public virtual int Id { get; private set; }
    public virtual string EMail { get; set; }
    ...
    public virtual bool IsActive { get; set; }
    public virtual int CompanyId { get; set; }
}
```

With a UserMap:

```
public class UserMap : ClassMap<User>
{
    public UserMap()
    {
        Table("Users");
        Id(x => x.Id, "UserId");
        Map(x => x.EMail);
        ...

        Join("CompanyUser", r =>
        {
            r.KeyColumn("UserId");
            r.Map(x => x.IsActive);
            r.Map(x => x.CompanyId);
            r.Fetch.Join();

        });

        ApplyFilter<CompanyFilter>("this_1_.CompanyId = :companyId");
    }
```

This actually works right now, but as you can see I'm having to include the alias name "this_1_" for the CompanyUser table in the filter... this doesn't sound correct, but if I leave the filter as is defined in the FilterDefinition class I get a Sql with a:

```
where this.CompanyId = ?p0
```

which is not mapped 'cos the CompanyId column comes from a different projection (CompanyUser as this_1_)

Is there a way to correct this and let nhibernate figure out the correct alias for the filter?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: I'd love to know the answer to this too. Did you find out a better solution?

Comment: @RenanMalkeStigliani No, I ended up just living with it for the time being, I haven't found a solution.... I'll make sure to post it here if I find it

Answer (score 0):

I think you must apply the filter on the join:

```
    Join("CompanyUser", r =>
    {
        r.KeyColumn("UserId");
        r.Map(x => x.IsActive);
        r.Map(x => x.CompanyId);
        r.Fetch.Join();

    }).ApplyFilter<CompanyFilter>("CompanyId = :companyId");
```

Comment: Thanks for the answere, I'm not sure that this solves my problem though, the "this_1_.CompanyId" reference being hardcoded in the mapping class... so when I join the user with other entities that have companyId, the "this_1_.companyId" something should be "this_2_"...

Comment: Can you try the new version (after my edit)? I think NHibernate parses the filter and adds the correct alias when needed.